# MSSQL database slow when move database on other disk

Tags: sql-server, performance, hard-drive

MSSQL Developer Edition, with many database online for test purposes.

To better handle disk space, I moved some databases to another disk. Moved databases perform slower than the original location (that was the default from setup).

I tested both disks with `winsat` and the speed are comparable. Additional disk has a lower maximum latency. Both are consumer SSD disks.

I don't understand what is the reason, and what to check further, any idea?

**ADDITION**
looks like, as soon I restore a database on the new location, it perform fine. If I left unused for a while, it slow down, kind of "sleep mode", but even if I continue to use database seems not to "wake up" again.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to update statistics and defrag existing indexes on the database you moved. Use [Ola Hallengren scripts](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance.html) which you can download from [here](https://ola.hallengren.com/downloads.html).

```
EXECUTE dbo.IndexOptimize
@Databases = 'USER_DATABASES',
@FragmentationLow = NULL,
@FragmentationMedium = 'INDEX_REORGANIZE,INDEX_REBUILD_ONLINE,INDEX_REBUILD_OFFLINE',
@FragmentationHigh = 'INDEX_REBUILD_ONLINE,INDEX_REBUILD_OFFLINE',
@FragmentationLevel1 = 5,
@FragmentationLevel2 = 30,
@UpdateStatistics = 'ALL',
@OnlyModifiedStatistics = 'Y'
```

Whenever I perform migrations or upgrades, I update statistics and defrag indexes to obtain the best performance.